# Prevent array item from being selected twice

Tags: javascript

How do I prevent a number being selected twice from an array within a for loop? In this case, I want to make sure **pictureNo** is unique each time.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        // Generate timeline items
        var timelineItemCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
        for(i=0;i<timelineItemCount;i++)
        {
            generateTimeline();
        }
    });

function generateTimeline() {
    // Select gender
    var genderArray = ['male','female'];
    var gender = genderArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*genderArray.length)]; 

    // Select profile picture - how do I prevent the same number from being selected once here
    var pictureNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19) + 1;

    // Create timeline entry    
    $('#home-page').append($('<div class="timeline-item"><img src="assets/img/' + gender + '_profile' + pictureNo + '.jpg" alt="" class="img-rounded profile"></div>'));    
}
```

Comment: try to create a conditon when gender is exist you should not print it. That's the solution I guess. A simple matter of condition.

Comment: Create a function which grabs a random number. And create a array which contains the previously chosen random numbers. Check if the new random number is has an index inside the array if it does then rerun the random function until you will have a unique random number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        // Generate timeline items
        var timelineItemCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1.
            selectedPicObj={};
        for(i=0;i<timelineItemCount;i++)
        {
            generateTimeline(selectedPicObj);
        }
    });

    function generateTimeline(selectedPicObj) {
    // Select gender
    var genderArray = ['male','female'], i=0;
    var gender = genderArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*genderArray.length)]; 

    // Select profile picture - how do I prevent the same number from being selected once here
    var pictureNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19) + 1;
        for(;i<19;i++){
            if(!selectedPicObj[pictureNo]){
                selectedPicObj[pictureNo] = true;
                break;
            }else{
                pictureNo++;
                if(pictureNo === 19){
                    pictureNo = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    // Create timeline entry    
    $('#home-page').append($('<div class="timeline-item"><img src="assets/img/' + gender + '_profile' + pictureNo + '.jpg" alt="" class="img-rounded profile"></div>'));    
}
```

Comment: Why so inefficient and complex for such a simple task?

Comment: Why its inefficient? And rather then using a library like underscore whick will be of few kbs you can use small code snippet. Now if we talk about efficiency, for an object lookup complexity is O(1) and then for looking for next object it will not be more than O(n). And internally all library has to check(including underscore)

Comment: There is O(n^2), I think, because of two nested loops. The complexity in unclear generateTimeline() function. It is difficult to imagine how it works

Comment: It is not O(n^2), It would be when your random number always give next number of previous value. Here when some random number is already there, it checks for the next value, or next if not available. In case of hashing, this is one of the ways to check in case of collision.

Comment: I've tested this code for output all items, and there are an experimental count of performed if-checks in the inner loop. 
10 items: 15-30 checks, 100 items: 300-900 checks, 1K items: 14K-30K checks, 10K items: 300K - 900K checks

Comment: Ok, now please share results with underscore.js and if someone  has to write one's own implementation. If you can suggest any optimization, I will be happy to learn :)

Comment: And this solution does not provide really random values, if output count less than all items count. It depends on previously generated values, so consequent numbers gets more chances.

Comment: I can rewrite my algorithm without underscore, and it changes nothing. I also tested both algorithms for 100K of items: ~2500 msec to ~115 msec, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try and store the randomly selected numbers so every time a new number is randomly selected you have a **condition** to compare it with the previously selected numbers. If the number was previously selected then a new random number should be selected.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array outside the for loop and store the random numbers being generated.
At each iteration of the for loop, check if the new random number belongs to the array.
When the for loop finishes, reset the array to the empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Lets define two arrays of male and female indices, genders array, shuffle them and pop some items. It is easy to do with Underscore.JS, for example:

```
var malesCount = 20;
var femalesCount = 20;

var profiles = {
  'male' : _.shuffle(_.range(1, malesCount + 1)),
  'female' : _.shuffle(_.range(1, femalesCount + 1)),
};

var genders = [];
for (var index = 0; index < malesCount; index++) {
  genders.push('male');
}
for (var index = 0; index < femalesCount; index++) {
  genders.push('female');
}
genders = _.shuffle(genders);

var gender;
var pictureNo;
var src;
while (gender = genders.pop()) {
  pictureNo = profiles[gender].pop();
  src = 'assets/img/' + gender + '_profile' + pictureNo + '.jpg';
  console.log(src);
}
```

I've tested this solution for 50K of males and 50K of females, it executes just in 115 msec.